# Multiple SubSelect Inner Joins Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to create multiple Z Scores [(value-AVG)/STD] within one query and filter them.

So far, I came up with this; before you look at it, however, theres some french words, "quartier" is like a district/borough and "prix" is a price.

```
SELECT ((t1.prix-A1.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z,
q.myId AS q_myId
FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t1 
LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t1.adresse_id=a.id
LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(t2.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(t2.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t2
    LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t2.adresse_id=a.id
    LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
    GROUP BY quartier_myId
) AS A1 ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId
```

It seems to work, however I'm not sure if Im doing this right, I only added one filtering condition but I will add up to 6 conditions and so far this method seems quite cumbersome for what it does.

Ultimately it would look like this

```
SELECT 
((t1.prix-A1.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z1,
((t1.prix-A2.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z2,
((t1.prix-AN.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS ZN,
All Relevant selects
FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t1 
All Relevant LEFT Joins
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(t2.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(t2.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t2
    LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t2.adresse_id=a.id
    LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
    GROUP BY quartier_myId
) AS A1 ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(t2.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(t2.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t3
    Other Joins
    Group By Other conditions
) AS A2 ON OtherConditions
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(tN.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(tN.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS tN
    Other Joins
    Group By Other conditions
) AS AN ON OtherConditions
```

This is in mysql, according to manual cross join = inner join = join. However from what I understood cross join is table X table, but in my case since it returns aggregates, I suppose its not t^2 but t*(number of aggregates) right ?

AM I right on the right track ? Optimization Wise ? Did I put my filtering at the right place ?

I basically wanna select all rows, find their averages function of their join values, calculate their Z Scores, and add them up within less than 5 sec and with around 1M data.

EDIT 1:

I'll simplify my question,

```
SELECT 
((t1.prix-A1.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z,
((t1.prix-A2.HMEAN)*100/A2.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z2,
q.myId AS q_myId,
c.myId AS c_myId,
s.myId as size_myId
FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t1 
LEFT JOIN Size AS s ON t1.size_id=s.id
LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t1.adresse_id=a.id
LEFT JOIN City AS c ON a.city_id=c.id
LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(t2.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(t2.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    s.myId as size_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t2
    LEFT JOIN Size AS s ON t2.size_id=s.id
    LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t2.adresse_id=a.id
    LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
    GROUP BY quartier_myId, size_myId
) AS A1 ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId
AS A2 on s.myId=A2.size_myId #<--------- Is this line possible ?
```

EDIT 3:

I ended up using temporary tables and duplicating them because views in my case were way slower than temp tables even though the underlying data was correctly indexed.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A1 AS (
SELECT AVG(t2.prix) AS HMEAN, 
    STD(t2.prix) AS STD_SAMPLE,
    s.myId AS size_myId,
    q.myId AS quartier_myId
    FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS t2
    LEFT JOIN Size AS s ON t2.size_id=s.id
    LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON t2.adresse_id=a.id
    LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON a.quartier_id=q.id
    GROUP BY quartier_myId,size_myId);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A2 LIKE A1; 
INSERT A2 SELECT * FROM A1;

SELECT 
((c.prix-A1.HMEAN)*100/A1.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z1,
((c.prix-A2.HMEAN)*100/A2.STD_SAMPLE) AS Z2,
q.myId AS quartier_myId,
s.myId AS size_myId
FROM immobilier_ad_blank AS c
LEFT JOIN Size AS s ON c.size_id=s.id
LEFT JOIN Adresse AS ad ON c.adresse_id=ad.id
LEFT JOIN Quartier AS q ON ad.quartier_id=q.id
JOIN A1 on A1.quartier_myId = q.myId
JOIN A2 AS A2 on A2.size_myId = s.myId
```

Basically, joining the same virtual table (subquery) === Views || Temp Tables
And to be honest, I might end up creating a permanent table and update it once a day....

Answer (score 2):

`CROSS JOIN ... ON condition` makes the cross join into an ordinary `INNER JOIN` or, for brevity, just `JOIN`. So don't worry about the combinatorial explosion. A correctly written `ON` condition prevents it.In short, forget about `CROSS JOIN`. Just write `JOIN`.

You can write your `JOIN` as something like this

```
 FROM table_a AS a
 JOIN table_b AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Or, you can express either table_a or table_b, or both, as subqueries. For example, you can write this query.

```
 FROM table_A AS a
 JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(id) id, district
           FROM table_b
          GROUP BY district
      ) AS b on a.id = b.id
```

In other words, you can use a physical table (`table_b`) or a virtual table (a subquery) interchangeably.

In your case, your subquery  is a four-column table: (HMEAN, STD_SAMPLE, quartier_myId, and size_myId) .

How will you join that table to the rest of the tables in your query?

You have the code

```
  JOIN (subquery) AS A1 ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId
```

But, to use the fourth column of your subquery (size_myId) you need to use it also for the JOIN.  To do this, put an `AND` in your `ON` clause. Do something like this:

```
  JOIN (subquery) AS A1   ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId 
                         AND s.myId = A.size_myId
```

If the meaning of s.myId is correct, that should give you a useful result.

Compound `ON` clauses are very useful. You can do such things as this:

```
  LEFT JOIN (subquery) AS A1   ON q.myId = A1.quartier_myId 
                              AND s.myId = A.size_myId
                              AND A.HMEAN > 7.5
```

to filter your results.

Comment: Right, but the `JOIN (subquery)` creates a table of aggregates with their IDs columns.  By adding more `on` conditions, the subquery would return a different aggregate from the virtual table. I would like to select lets say `JOIN (subqueryA) AS Aggregate1 ON condition1` and `JOIN(subqueryA) AS Aggregate 2 On condition 2 `. I dont wanna merge the conditions, otherwise the aggregates are different. I wanna select both aggregates meaning join multiple times this virtual table each with different conditions.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a separate subquery for each separate situation. Your queries get verbose in these cases. You might consider using views.

Comment: Your right, thats whats I tried originally but I had performance issue, ended up using temp tables